# Trying to create a "Do not show this box again" window in Tkinter---issue with callback function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a program using tkinter, which will display a Toplevel at startup containing license information. I want to provide a checkbox on the Toplevel so that the user won't have to see the license information again when running the program in the future. I haven't really found much on how to do this kind of thing, so if there is a much simpler way, I'm all ears.

The process of determining whether to launch the Toplevel is performed by a function, `license_window` which is executed at startup.

I've started by creating a simple text file, `config.txt` which contains the single character '0'. When the user starts the program for this first time, `license_window` will check to determine the contents of `config.txt`. If it is '0', which it will be at the first startup, then the Toplevel appears with the license info along with a close button and "do no show again" checkbox.
If the user selects the checkbox, then the '0' in config.txt is replaced by '1'. and the **Toplevel should close**. In this case, when the program is run again, the Toplevel won't appear since the entry in `config.txt` is no longer '0'.

Here's some of the relevant code, where Toplevel is named `info_window`. I haven't included the code for a scrolling textbox appearing directly above the close button and checkbox.

```
def license_window():
    my_file = open("config.txt", "r+")
    content = my_file. read()

    if content=='0': #only create the Toplevel if the content is '0'
       info_window=Toplevel()
       info_window.wm_title('Software License')

       def close_window(): #Simply close Toplevel if button chosen below.
           info_window.destroy()

       def update_config(): 
           #Change text entry in config.txt to 1 if checkbox below is selected
           my_file = open("config.txt", "r+")
           content = my_file.read()
           content=content.replace('0','1')
           with open('config.txt', 'w') as file:
               file.write(content)
           close_window

    
       close_button=Button(info_window,text="Close",command=close_window)
       close_button.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True)

       choice = IntVar()
       choice_box = Checkbutton(info_window, text='Do not show this 
       again',variable=choice, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=update_config)
       choice_box.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True)
```

When I run this, selecting `choice_box` does indeed change the content of my text file from a '0' to a '1' as desired. However, selecting `choice_box` **does not close the Toplevel**, which is what the last line of `update_config()` is intended to do. (I don't want the user to have to select the close button separately.)

Am I making a silly callback function error?

Comment: Looks like you forgot the parentheses to call close_window

Comment: It's always the simplest things. I don't quite get why parentheses are needed there but not when I refer to the function inside my close button.

Comment: Parentheses call the function immediately. When you create the close button, you don't want to close it immediately, you want it closed later, when the button is pressed.